# Truffle exits with "Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount." error when migrating the 1_initial_migration.js

Tags: truffle, parity, truffle-migration

I am trying to migrate the basic truffle example (the one created via `truffle init`) to rospten using Parity but I get the following error even thought the contract is correctly deployed on Rospten:

> Using network 'development'.
>
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   Deploying Migrations...
>   ... 0x3f8cd1b1e98935feb4616e810f4ce0d6ebfbd7355ea8a8e9695a490173d8446e
>
> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. 
>   Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
>       at Object.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/buil/cli.bundled.js:218485:46)
>
> ```
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:34886:25
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:220423:9
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:72910:11
> at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:204149:9
> at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:205574:13)
> at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73069:18)
> at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73359:12)
> at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73514:12)
> at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73474:24)
> ```

As you can see from here the contract is correctly deployed: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3f8cd1b1e98935feb4616e810f4ce0d6ebfbd7355ea8a8e9695a490173d8446e

This is the code for 1_initial_migrations.js:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations, {from: "0x004995b1caD48E77e7A53e535Bb82c8189B80632", gas:2000000});
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the answer to my own question.

It all comes down to the following bug in parity resulting in a race condition between getCode and getTransactionReceipt: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/5538

If parity is executed in geth compatibility mode via the `--geth` flag, then truffle migration works as expected.